# OpenAPI/Swagger: Using a callback intended for the client to callback on

Tags: amazon-s3, swagger, openapi, openapi-generator

I'm defining an OpenAPI 3.0 spec for an existing service which involves the client uploading a file. Because of file size restrictions in AWS Gateway, the client cannot upload the file directly to the service.

Instead, an API endpoint returns a pre-signed URL to the client which can then be used to upload the file to S3. Specifically, the client has to call:

1. `GET /uploadurl`  ->  `{ "presigned_url": "string" }`
2. `PUT {presigned_url}` ->  200

I would like to document this clearly in the OpenAPI spec.

Additionally, it would be ideal to have the second operation encapsulated in the SDK generated from the spec, i.e. so the client SDK has a method which takes the `presigned_url` and the file as params.

The two options thought of so far is:

- defining a Callback on the `/uploadurl` operation
- defining a separate parameterised path with a static S3 URL as the server/base path.

The second option is good as a distinct method will be generated in the SDK but it is also awkward as bath path/region has to be defined statically in the spec and the presigned_url would have to be parsed by the client to get the path/query params.

The callback approach doesn't generate a method in the SDK and it seems like it isn't what the callback feature is intended for, i.e. this is allowing the client to callback to the server not the other way around.

Below is an excerpt of the OpenAPI spec for the callback:

```
paths:
  /uploadurl:
    get:
      tags:
        - upload
      operationId: getUploadUrl
      description: 'Returns a pre-signed URL to upload a file to the S3 bucket'
      parameters:
        - name: filename
          in: query
          description: The name of the file
          required: true
          schema:
            type: string
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Successful operation.
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: object
                properties:
                  presigned_url:
                    type: string
                    format: uri
        '422':
          description: Validation error. A filename must be provided.
        '5XX':
          description: Unexpected error.
      callbacks:
        upload:   # Event name
          '{response.body#/presigned_url}':   # The callback URL,
                                            # Refers to the passed URL
            put:
              description: >
                This callback is provided for the client to upload their dataset to 
                our S3 bucket using presigned_url provided in the response. 
                The file must be compressed as tar.gz
              requestBody:
                content:
                  application/octet-stream:
                    schema:
                      type: string
                      format: binary
              responses:   # Expected responses to the callback message
                '200':
                  description: File uploaded successfully
```

If I could define a path entirely parameterised rather than being relative to the server then that would be ideal. Has anyone dealt with such a use-case in Swagger?